# Creating permutations of all possible non-repeated combinations within N elements

Tags: matlab, permutation, combinatorics

I was wondering if i) there is a name for the following combinatorics problem; ii) is there a way to code it within Matlab?

I have N elements, and would like to generate all possible permutations of non-repeated combinations with varying bracket sizes. For instance, for N = 5 elements, we have the following possible permutations:

- Max group combination size of 5: (ABCDE)
- Max group combination size of 4: (A) (BCDE); (BCDE) (A); (B) (ACDE); (ACDE) (B); (C) (ABDE); (D) (ABCE); (E)(ABCD) etc.
- Max group combination size of 3: (AB) (CDE); (A) (B) (CDE); (AC) (BCD); (A) (C) (BCD) etc.
- Max group combination size of 2: (AB) (CD) (E); (AB) (C) (D) (E); (AB) (CE) (D) etc.
- Max group combination size of 1: (A) (B) (C) (D) (E); (B) (C) (D) (E) (A); etc.

Note that, within the brackets, order does not matter i.e. they are just combinations. But beyond the brackets, permutation must occur, for instance, (AB) (CDE) and (CDE) (AB) are two possible permutations.

Comment: It looks like you are just grouping and doing a `perms`; do you want to come up with you own solution first?

Comment: @GameOfThrows: With perms you would generate `(A) (BCDE)` in 4!=24 different orders.

Comment: @yl91: What should the function do? Are you looking for a generator which creates all possible solutions or a function which generates random samples? While both seems to be very similar, possible implementations can be totally different.

Comment: @Dan he said that within the brackets order does not matter, so I assumed that (A) (BCDE), (A) (BCED) (A) (BECD) etc would all count? Or have I mis-understood the question.

Comment: @GameOfThrows: I would interpret "The order does not matter" as "These solutions are all the same", but I might be wrong. yl91 if I am right there are just 3 additional solutions missing for the "Max group combination size of 4" category. If this is right adding them and removing the "etc". might be a good idea for clarification.

Comment: @Daniel ahhhh is that what he meant.. I was making it difficult in which case.

Comment: i) You're looking for all permutations of partitions of a set.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a few combinations (sorry :-) ) of `perms` and `nchoosek`   Just generate your partitions and then permute each of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer to (i).  You need to be aware of [The Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).  Almost certainly your question is an example of one of these, but from your description it is unclear to me which way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for all your responses. They are greatly appreciated. Someone from the Mathworks forum was able to answer it.

In short, the problem is a "Partition Problem", followed by the permutation of the solution generated.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/265601-creating-permutations-of-all-possible-non-repeated-combinations-within-n-elements#answer_207742